# Keep checkbox checked after is hide

Tags: html, angular

How can I keep a checkbox checked after it's displayed on button click? Is this possible? [Here is a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frmkwm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

.html

```
<a href="#tab1success" data-toggle="tab">
  <h5>
    <button mat-button class="btn filter" (click)="changeSummary()">Summary</button>
  </h5>
</a>

<div id="tab1success">
  <div *ngIf="bool">
    <label class="btn btn-light btn-filter" id="bttns">
      <input type="checkbox" name="name1" autoComplete="off"> check1
    </label>&nbsp;
    <label class="btn btn-light btn-filter" id="bttns">
      <input type="checkbox" name="name2" autoComplete="off"> check2
    </label>&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
bool = false

changeSummary() {
    if (!this.bool) {
      this.bool = true;
    }
    else {
      this.bool = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can I suggest this variant of changeSummary: 
`changeSummary() {
   bool=!bool
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<div *ngIf="bool">
```

by

```
<div [hidden]="!bool">
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to go for handling this scenario using `Forms` API, which will be cleaner way to do this, either use template driven or model driven form. Remember the value inside component and as soon as template disabled, binding will take care of displaying what you have inside model.

```
//Create formSet object which will be holding all radio button
formSet = {};
```

**Html**

```
//Assign `ngModel` to each of input
<label class="btn btn-light btn-filter" id="bttns">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="formSet.name" name="name2" autoComplete="off"> check1
</label>&nbsp;
<label class="btn btn-light btn-filter" id="bttns">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="formSet.name2" name="name2" autoComplete="off"> check2
</label>&nbsp;
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mezukh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I'm not offensive about the accepted answer, but I personally can't digest to keep something inside DOM tree which is not visible. `*ngIf` was suitable there, rather using forms would suffice the purpose here.